# How to sent data from Azure HDInsight Kafka to Azure Event Hub

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub, azure-hdinsight

Anyone knows how can I send data from Azure HDInsight Kafka 1.1 (HDI 4.0) to an Azure Event hub?

I have searched and could not find any good solutions. I thought of setting up mirror maker inside the HD Insight but I would like to avoid that and also would like to avoid creating any other 3rd resources to connect both.

Comment: You cannot do it w/o a connector. Kafka server doesn't provide any sort of built-in replicator.

Comment: What about HDInsights and extensions or scripts?

Comment: I am not knowledgeable about HDInsight extensions. Maybe an expert can help on that question.